# New LVM VDO logical volume inactive at startup, even with "--activate y" parameter

Tags: linux, debian, lvm, fstab, vdo

I'm trying to make LVM VDO work on my Debian 11.3 (test VM installed from scratch). I've shared my installation procedure [here](https://github.com/dm-vdo/vdo/issues/47) if someone wants to reproduce the problem. Now I'm stuck with a "basic" problem which is : the logical volume is inactive at startup. After VDO is compiled and installed, I run the following script:

```sh
# Create zeroed VDO volume and format to ext4
DESTINATION_LVM_VG="/dev/Pepper-Potts-vg"
VDOLV_NAME="ZEROED-VDOLV-1"
VDOLV_PATH="$DESTINATION_LVM_VG/$VDOLV_NAME"

lvcreate -y --vdopool "ZEROED-VDOPOOL-1" --name $VDOLV_NAME --activate y --compression n --deduplication n --size 12G --virtualsize 24G --config "allocation/vdo_slab_size_mb=8192" $DESTINATION_LVM_VG && \
mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard $VDOLV_PATH

# Reconfigure /etc/fstab to mount zeroed VDO partition to /mnt/ZEROED-VDOLV-1
MOUNT_POINT="/mnt/$VDOLV_NAME"
mkdir $MOUNT_POINT
DM_VDOLV_PATH=($(lvs --noheadings --options "lv_dm_path" $VDOLV_PATH))
# We use "@" because $DIRECTORY_TO_MOVE contains "/"
echo "$DM_VDOLV_PATH    $MOUNT_POINT    ext4    defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=0,x-systemd.requires=vdo.service  0   0" >> /etc/fstab
mount -a
```

and it works well but rebooting the VM fails because /dev/mapper/Pepper-Potts-vg-ZEROED--VDOPOOL--1 (`$DM_VDOLV_PATH`) no longer exists (I've checked). So I investigated with `lvscan` and found out that the logical volume doesn't exist in /dev/mapper/ because it is inactive. Doing `vgchange -ay` solves the boot problem but at next reboot it is stuck again.

I tried the same script with a "classic"/non-VDO logical volume and I don't have the problem as the logical volume stay active.

Edit 1: `lvs` output is as follow:

```
LV               VG              Attr       LSize   Pool             Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
ZEROED-VDOLV-1   Pepper-Potts-vg vwi-XXv-X-  24,00g ZEROED-VDOPOOL-1
ZEROED-VDOPOOL-1 Pepper-Potts-vg dwi-XX--X-  12,00g
home             Pepper-Potts-vg -wi-ao----  <9,08g
root             Pepper-Potts-vg -wi-ao----  <3,18g
swap_1           Pepper-Potts-vg -wi-ao---- 976,00m
tmp              Pepper-Potts-vg -wi-ao---- 316,00m
var              Pepper-Potts-vg -wi-ao----   1,37g
```

Edit 2: I ran `systemctl status /dev/mapper/Pepper--Potts--vg-ZEROED--VDO` and it gave me the following :

```
● dev-mapper-Pepper\x2d\x2dPotts\x2d\x2dvg\x2dZEROED\x2d\x2dVDO.device - /dev/mapper/Pepper--Potts--vg-ZEROED--VDO
     Loaded: loaded
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

While other LVs are `loaded` and `active (plugged)` :

```
● dev-mapper-Pepper\x2d\x2dPotts\x2d\x2dvg\x2dhome.device - /dev/mapper/Pepper--Potts--vg-home
   Follow: unit currently follows state of sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d4.device
     Loaded: loaded
     Active: active (plugged) since Sat 2022-05-14 19:00:24 CEST; 5min ago
     Device: /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-4
```

Any idea ? Maybe I should create a virtual device as the other default logical volume has ?

Edit 3: No, virtual device (/dev/dm-X) is created by LVM when doing lvcreate

Suggestions :

- Does Debian has any logical volume list to activate at boot ? As it is/was the case for [CentOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213027/lvm-volume-is-inactive-after-reboot-of-centos) and RHEL ?
- Would it be [this old Debian bug](https://serverfault.com/questions/199185/logical-volumes-are-inactive-at-boot-time) ??

Comment: Show the `lvs` output (which will include, among other potentially relevant bits, the *activation skip* flag).

Comment: @anx Thanks for your answer, I've edited the post with the `lvs` command output

Comment: Man page says `X` means unknown. There should be vdo-specifics tools to inquire directly, and errors logged via kernel (dmesg) and/or journal if those fail, too. Note that you can pass device paths directly to systemd, so try `systemctl status /dev/whatever`

Comment: @anx I didn't have the idea to check about these attributes, thanks.

The only up-to-date documentation that I found is : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmvdo.7.html
I didn't find any information about mount problem on Red Hat, probably because they don't use LVM. I ran your command and edited my original post

Answer (score 1):

Solved [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/upk8rn/comment/i8mhg07/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

1. My `/etc/fstab` line was directly taken from [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/deduplicating_and_compressing_storage/deploying-vdo_deduplicating-and-compressing-storage#mounting-a-vdo-volume_deploying-vdo) but couldn't work as `vdo.service` no longer exist ; VDO module is now integrated with LVM. So now I run:

```sh
echo "$DM_VDOLV_PATH    $MOUNT_POINT    ext4    defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0   0" >> /etc/fstab
```

2. I find out that `lvm2-activation-generator` is not a package to install using `apt install ...` but is packaged with apt and can be used by adding `event_activation = 0` configuration line in LVM configuration file (`/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`). This configuration file is loaded during the initialisation phase of LVM ([source](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/lvm2/lvm.conf.5.en.html)). Once "enabled", this generator generates systemd mount units for each `/etc/fstab` entry (in `/run/systemd/generator/` directory) and the system starts correctly.